# Determine a running instance's VM class in app engine flexible

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've got auto scaling on in my app engine flexible (PHP) app.yaml file. Is there a `gcloud` or console way to figure out the machine class of the instances that have been assigned to my service?

I know that I can set the resources I need in terms of disk and RAM in my yaml file, but this is a *minimum*; actual allocated machines may be different. I'm looking to determine what was allocated after the machine is running.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77211619) already opened for this feature, however it isn't yet available.

As a workaround, you can use the Google API Explorer and use the Stackdriver Logging API v2 > logging.entries.list [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/logging/v2/logging.entries.list). You should get relevant information by entering the following details:

```
fields: entries/protoPayload 
Request body: filter: resource.type="gce_instance_template" AND protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instanceTemplates.insert" AND protoPayload.resourceName:"/global/instanceTemplates/aef-" 
projectIds: <YOUR_PROJECT_IDS>
```

You'll see the required information under "machineType".